# Store feature flags for iOS app

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, plist, userdefaults

In my app I have some features that use to be executed only few times. 
For example on-boarding guide should be shown once, and some tool tips explaining app features need to be shown only before user finally use this features once or twice.

So I need to store it somewhere. Right now I am using UserDefaults for it. This approach is rather simple but no so elegant when you need to store and update many feature flags.

Maybe there is some great solution for storing feature flags?

P.S.
Core Data or Realm look to heavy for this task. While .plist files looks better

Comment: I should've added this as a comment. Try KeychainSwift. It's more secure then UserDefaults but it's very easy to use. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/KeychainSwift/9.0.2/

Comment: This is exactly what UserDefaults is for.

Answer (score 1):

First off, as rmaddy points out in the comments this is exactly what `UserDefaults` was designed for. I get the feeling you are using it in such a way that it has become a burden that's very unfortunate. Here are a few things you can do to make using it much more straightforward and maintainable.

1. Create an extension of `UserDefaults` in a separate file.
2. Add computed values to the extension, using the `#function` keyword you can assign the value's name to `UserDefaults` as the key without using a hard-coded string that can be mis-typed later in code.
3. Use an `enum` to encapsulate related values such as your feature flags.
4. Depending on your usage, you can add custom functionality to the computed values or connivence functions.

**UserDefaults.swift**

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Features

/// Names of Features to be later accessed by raw value.
enum Features: String {
    case FeatureZ
    case FeatureX
    case FeatureW
}


extension UserDefaults {

    // MARK: - Onboarding

    /// Indicates whether or not the user completed account setup.
    /// - Returns: Bool
    var finishedAcountSetup: Bool {
        get { return bool(forKey: #function) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }

    /// Indicates whether or not the user completed the first part of onboarding
    /// - Returns: Bool
    var primaryOnboarding: Bool {
        get { return bool(forKey: #function) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }

    // counter for displaying the tool tip
    private var counterForToolTip: Int {
        get { return integer(forKey: #function) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }

    // Indicates whether or not the tool tip be shown
    var shouldShowToolTip: Bool {
        get {
            if (counterForToolTip > 2) {
                counterForToolTip = 0
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    var featureFlags: [String] {
        get {
            guard let array = stringArray(forKey: #function) else {
                return []
            }
            return array
        }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }

    // Convience functions
    /// Sets all onboarding values
    func setAllOnboarding(to: Bool) {
        var onboardingValues = [finishedAcountSetup, primaryOnboarding]

        for (index, _) in onboardingValues.enumerated() {

            onboardingValues[index] = to
        }
    }

    /// Increment the tool tip counter by a integer
    /// If the counter is > 2 then the tool tip can show.
    func incrementToolTipCounter(by: Int = 1){
        counterForToolTip += by
    }



}
```

**Meanwhile, elsewhere...**

```
UserDefaults.standard.featureFlags.append(Features.FeatureX.rawValue)
UserDefaults.standard.finishedAcountSetup = true
UserDefaults.standard.setAllOnboarding(to: false)
UserDefaults.standard.incrementToolTipCounter()

for (index, _ ) in UserDefaults.standard.featureFlags.enumerated() {
    print("\(UserDefaults.standard.featureFlags[index])")
}

if (UserDefaults.standard.featureFlags.contains(Features.FeatureX.rawValue)) {
    // Do something
}

// etc.
```